# HP-UX 11.11 - Incoming connection problem

Tags: networking, hp-ux

I have machine with fresh installed HP-UX 11.11.
All seem to work well, but there is one problem - while I have no problem to ping my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, access internet etc from HP-UX machine, I cannot ping HP-UX machine itself, therefore I cannot ssh, ftp and other things.
Could anyone suggest me what could I do in order to make my HP-UX machine available in the network?
(I have googled and found some info about ipfilter but I cannot find any signs of ipfilter in /etc/rc.config.d)

***HP-UX ip address is 10.0.2.15 - can ping Linux machine on 192.168.0.102

Linux ip address is 192.168.0.102 - cannot ping HP-UX machine on 10.0.2.15***

lanscan gives lan0 interface only, IP address is 10.0.2.15

I am pinging my Linux machine (192.168.0.102) from the HP-UX machine

**ping 192.168.0.102** gives the following:
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102, icmp_sq=0, time=8, ms

**ping community.hpe.com** gives the following:
64 bytes from 99.86.161.54, icmp_sq=0, time=45, ms

Cannot ping from my Linux (192.168.0.102) machine

**ping 10.0.2.15** gives the following:

From 10.244.232.2 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
From 10.244.232.2 icmp_seq=2 Time to live exceeded
From 10.244.232.2 icmp_seq=3 Time to live exceeded
From 10.244.232.2 icmp_seq=4 Time to live exceeded

**ssh dragon@10.0.2.15** gives the following
ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: No route to host

(sshd is up and running on the HP-UX machine, ps -ef | grep sshd shows that)

Comment: Does the HP-UX system have the `sshd`, `ftpd` and other services running?

Comment: sshd is up and running,

Comment: Can you clarify which machine is which and which each command is executed from? My immediate response from looking at the question was that one was on network 198.168.0.0/16 and the other on 10.0.0.0/8. Both of which are private networks which are not [normally] supposed to be forwarded by [b]routers across the different networks.

Comment: HP-UX ip address is 10.0.2.15 - can ping Linux machine on 192.168.0.102, and 
Linux ip address is 192.168.0.102 - cannot ping HP-UX machine on 10.0.2.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact your network administrator.

The `Time to live exceeded` error suggests a network routing issue: any IP packet has a Time-to-live (TTL) value which is (supposed to be) decremented each time the packet passes through a router. If the value reaches zero, the router will not pass the packet on, but instead transmits a "time to live exceeded" ICMP error packet back to the original sender. This stops misrouted packets from travelling through the net forever.

The fact that you get that error message when trying to ping the new HP-UX system from Linux, but not vice versa, suggests that some router (or possibly a hardware firewall) in the network between those systems is misconfigured and sending any "new" packets intended to the HP-UX system to a wrong route, causing them to go around in circles until the packets' TTL runs out. You might want to run a traceroute from the Linux host to the HP-UX host to provide evidence of the routing loop.